# Combining expressions and variables to list

Tags: list-manipulation, expression-manipulation

I thought this one was easy, but no! How do I get from

```
u = 7; k = 9; r = 4;
```

to

```
{{u, 7}, {k, 9}, {r, 4}}
```

without using

```
c = {"u", "k", "r"}
{c, {u, k, r}}\[Transpose]
```

Because I have many expressions and typing `" "` is tedious. I tried several variations of `Hold`, `Unevaluated`, `ToString`... Is there an easy shortcut?

Comment: Or maybe just a beginner solution like `ClearAll[u, k, r];
c = ToString /@ (b = {u, k, r})
u = 7; k = 9; r = 4;
{c, b}\[Transpose]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
ClearAll[f]
SetAttributes[f, {HoldAll, Listable}]
f[x_] := {ToString @ Unevaluated @ x, x}

u = 7; k = 9; r = 4;

f @ {u, k, r}
```

{{"u", 7}, {"k", 9}, {"r", 4}}

```
ToExpression[%]
```

{{7, 7}, {9, 9}, {4, 4}}

Answer (score 6):

another possible option is

```
u = 7; k = 9; r = 4;
ClearAll[f];
SetAttributes[f, {HoldFirst, Listable}]
f[x_] := {OwnValues[x][[1, 1]], x}
```

And now

```
f[{u, k, r}]
```

Gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can't get `{{u, 7}, {k, 9}, {r, 4}}` as variables will be evaluated to their value right away. So have to either use string representation or Hold and friends.

Answer (score 5):

Use an attribute "HoldFirst" to prevent the replacement of u by its value. And then use "SymbolName" to get the name of the symbol:

```
Clear[f];
SetAttributes[f, {HoldFirst, Listable}];
f[u_] := {SymbolName@Unevaluated@u, u};

u = 7; k = 9; r = 4;
f[{u, k, r}]

{{"u", 7}, {"k", 9}, {"r", 4}}{{"u", 7}, {"k", 9}, {"r", 4}}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use `Definition`:

```
SetAttributes[f, {HoldFirst, Listable}];
f[x_] := MapAt[ToExpression, StringSplit@StringDelete[ToString[Definition[x]], "="], 2];

u = 7; k = 9; r = 4;

f[{u, k, r}]

(*{{"u", 7}, {"k", 9}, {"r", 4}}*)
```